opencv python уменьшить temeout ожидания кдара
При попытке считать кадр с ip камеры по rtsp запросу все отрабатывает успешно, но если указать rtsp запрос неверным, кадр ожидается 30 сек. Не нашел способа уменьшить это время. Если кто-то знает как уменьшить это время, и в случае неверного запроса,например, сразу выводть false, буду очень благодарен, спасиибо!
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(TwoLink)
ждет 30 сек и выполняет дальше код

Через cv::CAP_GSTREAMER
